# I2C: BitBanging Read/Write Issue with Pic16f877A ( OSC = 11.0592MHz )

Tags: pic, i2c, mplabx

Referring [This Link] ([I2C: Unable to Read Multiple Byte using Bit-Banging method](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/185110/i2c-unable-to-read-multiple-byte-using-bit-banging-method/185303#185303)).

I created an I2C BitBanging library for Pic16f877A. But I am unable to Read/Write the EEPROM.

My Pin Configuration are :

```
SCK : RB0
SDATA_OUT : RB1
SDATA_IN : RB2
```

Rest code remains the same.

Possibly, The issue could be of the delay function as I am using OSC = 11.0592 MHZ with Pic16f877A. 
but tried increasing the delay by 2 times. Issue remains the same.

Also,

```
#pragma config  FOSC    =   HS
```

Can any one help me with Possible issues and way to rectify the issue.

Note: Code remains the same as the link says. Only Pin and its required registers are changed for Pic16f877A.

Comment: Have you looked at the SCL and SDA lines with a scope?

Comment: I haven't read the datasheet for that EEPROM but isn't ~11MHz a bit fast for I2C?

Comment: @RogerRowland, thanks for your suggestion. As you suggested, I checked the maximum frequency for I2C is 400KHz. I can't change the Oscillator, so what would be the better way to  calculate the delay ??

Comment: @skg Just insert delays into your bit banging code.

Comment: @RogerRowland, I am already using delay in my code. Just I need to increase the delay time. But How much , that i need to calculate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I caught my mistake.

Link provide just works fine. It was my mistake. While modifying the functions call, I deleted initI2C() function call. Which was causing the issue.

Also, Crystal value should be

```
#define Crystal_Value       12          // MHz
```

Thanks everyone for your valuable suggestions, that helped me improving my code.

Answer (score 1):

If all the code is exactly the same you have a mistake here :

```
#define Crystal_Value       8          // MHz
```

you should replace this line by:

```
#define Crystal_Value       11          // MHz
```

at the condition 11MHz is really the value of your system oscillator and not the only the one of your crystal oscillator.

Comment: thanks for your response. I already did this. " #define Crystal_Value 11.0592 //MHz "

Comment: Is 11MHz the frequency of your crystal or the frequency of your system? Some key word defines it

Comment: Its Crystal Frequency